# @BeforeEach not affect the Test, and the object not initialized - Eclipse with JUNIT

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have created a simple project with Eclipse which uses JUNIT 5.

The Account Object should initialized well, before each test, but actually the method doesn't recognize the object and return null exception in the test.

I have tried solution from other questions.

All my imports look fine. And at the run configuration it's defined to use jUnit 5.

What is the problem ? Thanks

**The test:**

```
package account;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class AccountTest {
    Account account;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Account account = new Account();
        System.out.println("Hi" + account.owner);
    }
    
    @Test  
    void assertBeforeEachWorking() {

        System.out.println("Befroe each? ");
        System.out.println(account.owner);
//      assertEquals("default owner2", account2.owner, "owner name not right" );
    }
```

}

**Account:**

```
package account;

public class Account {
    
    int amount ;
    String owner = "default owner";

}
```

[image: Run Configuration]

[image: Test-Result]

Comment: Your `@BeforeEach` method doesn't initialize your `account` field but creates a new local variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rob Spoor pointed at the comment, I was mistakenly creating a local variable at the method.

changing to:

```
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        account = new Account();
        System.out.println("Hi" + account.owner);
        
    }
```

Have solved the problem.

I leave this question for maybe in the future this mistake will happen to others.